# remove duplicate values from vector and prompt user to enter a new value

Tags: matlab

I have the vector numbers which has 6 elements from user input. I want to remove any duplicate value and replace it by another input (without the use of "unique" or similar).

I tried:

```
myvec=zeros(1,6);
disp('Choose numbers from 1 to 55')
for i=1:6
    myvec(i)=input('');
    if (find(myvec(i)<1 | myvec(i)>55))
        disp('Enter new value')
        myvec(i)=input('');
    end
     if myvec(i+1)==myvec(i)
         myvec(i+1)==input('');
     end
end
```

The problem is:

1) The statement below is correct?

```
if myvec(i+1)==myvec(i)
         myvec(i+1)==input('');
       end
```

2) When running it gives out of bounds because the vector length is 6 and I am trying to access i+1 .I tried to use the for loop from 2:7 but then it adds in the myvec vector the zero as first element.

Thank you!

Comment: Why the restriction of not using unique? This seems like using a hammer to drive a screw in the wall. Or is it that you're asking to solve your homework?

Comment: It's not homework.I just want to figure how can I do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `while` loop?

```
myvec = NaN(1,6);
ii = 0;
disp('Choose numbers from 1 to 55');
while any( isnan(myvec) )
    tmp = input('');
    if tmp > 1 && tmp < 55 
       % proper input. check for duplicate
       if ( ii == 0 ) || ( ii > 0 && all( myvec(1:ii) ~= tmp ) )
           ii = ii+1;
           myvec(ii) = tmp;
       end
    end
end
```

A small remark, [it is best not to use `i` and `j` as variables in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: How does your algorithm stores the first element of `myvec`? As long `i==0` the `if` condition never gets true.

Comment: @Shai:Ok, thanks!I changed NaN with zeros and isnan with "findmyvec==0".\